# Why is github trying to download a file that doesn't exist?

Tags: python, github

I can't upload my code to github. error: remote: error: File vendor/firefox/libxul.so is 143.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB.
But such a file has not been in the folder for a long time, it has been deleted.

Comment: Git must push the whole history. Even if you've `git rm` the file it remains in history. It must be removed from your history. Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in the Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository)

Comment: I get error:
Cannot create a new backup.
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f.
How to force overwrite a local copy with -f ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that error is coming from. Ask another question, please.

Comment: I entered the command **git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f MY_FILE' HEAD**.
This command from your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository).
I got an inscription:
Cannot create a new backup. A previous backup already exists in refs/original/ Force overwriting the backup with -f. 
My question: What to do next?

Comment: You can read the [`git-filter-branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) about what the backup is and what `-f` does. `git-filter-branch` is a complicated command, use the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890278/14660) instead.